Compose Lambert W and exponential in a numerically stable manner
I'm looking for a numerically stable way to evaluate
$$
W_0(a \exp(b)),
$$
where $W_0$ is the main branch of the Lambert W function, and $a > 0$. When $b$ is large, computing $\exp(b)$ can be infeasible, due to overflows. But, it believe it should be possible to compute the result I want, since
$$
W_0(z) \approx \ln(z) - \ln(\ln(z)),
$$
and therefore
$$
W_0(z) \approx \ln(a) + b + \ln(\ln(a) + b).
$$
So the value I want to compute should not 'explode' even when $b$ is large. Are there some properties I can use to avoid computing $\exp(b)$, and get the result I desire?
Ideally, re-using an existing implementation which computes $W$, such as the one in SciPy, without writing a numerical method myself.

It turns out that an answer already exists, in the form of the Wright $\omega$ function (see citation), which for a positive number $z$ is:
$$
\omega(z) = W_0(\exp(z)),
$$
It is already efficiently implemented in SciPy, in scipy.special.wrightomega. See here for documentation.
Thus:
$$
W_0(a \exp(b)) = W_0(\exp(b + \ln(a)) = \omega(b + \ln(a))
$$
References
Corless, Robert M.; Jeffrey, D. J., The Wright (\omega) function, Calmet, Jacques (ed.) et al., Artificial intelligence, automated reasoning, and symbolic computation.
